# How to transform 3d world matrix to fly an aircraft?

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, translate-animation, kinematics

I am programming a simple flight game in directX. I've modeled the aircraft and successfully imported it in the game. I made an input controller successfully. I made the turning left, right, up and down successfully.

I planned to have 3 vectors that keeps the roll, pitch and yaw axis of aircraft while he is flying.

```
DirectX::XMFLOAT3 flightDirection, flightRight, flightUp;
```

Initial states of vectors are:

```
flightDirection(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
flightRight(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
flightUp(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

```
if (newPointerPosition.x != pointerPosition.x || newPointerPosition.y != pointerPosition.y)
{
    xPointer = (newPointerPosition.x / resources->GetLogicalSize().Width) - 0.5f;
    yPointer = (newPointerPosition.y / resources->GetLogicalSize().Height) - 0.5f;
    rollAngle = xPointer;
    yawAngle = xPointer;
    pitchAngle = yPointer;

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&roll,XMMatrixRotationAxis(XMLoadFloat3(&flightDirection), rollAngle));
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&pitch, XMMatrixRotationAxis(XMLoadFloat3(&flightRight), pitchAngle));
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&yaw, XMMatrixRotationAxis(XMLoadFloat3(&flightUp), yawAngle));

    rotate = DirectX::XMMatrixMultiply(XMLoadFloat4x4(&pitch),  DirectX::XMMatrixMultiply(XMLoadFloat4x4(&yaw), XMLoadFloat4x4(&roll)));

    auto d = XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3(&flightDirection), rotate);
    position.x = XMVectorGetX(d);
    position.y = XMVectorGetY(d);
    position.z = XMVectorGetZ(d);
    XMStoreFloat3(&flightDirection, d);

    temp = DirectX::XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3(&flightRight), rotate);
    XMStoreFloat3(&flightRight, temp);

    temp = DirectX::XMVector3Transform(XMLoadFloat3(&flightUp), rotate);
    XMStoreFloat3(&flightUp, temp);

    pointerPosition = newPointerPosition;
}
translation._41 += position.z*0.01f;
translation._42 += position.y*0.01f;
translation._43 += position.x*0.01f;

world->Transform(XMLoadFloat4x4(&scale), rotate, XMLoadFloat4x4(&translation));
```

So this is my algorithm. First, position of the mouse sets the angle for rotations (angle is limited -0.5f < angle < 0.5f). Then I create a rotation matrixes around unit vectors that keep aircraft axis. rotate is the R matrix. After that I calculate new unit vectors that keep aircraft axis. Finally I add components of flightDirection to the translation matrix to get new position of an Aircraft.

My problem is that my algorithm doesn't work the way I intended. Something is calculating wrong and my aircraft flies in wrong and random directions after i move the mouse.

Please tell me how to correct this algorithm or give me the link of example how moving an object in 3D space is done.

Best Regards,
Antun

Comment: You add `position` to the translation. Shouldn't it be `flightDirection`? Your rotation angles could also be a bit big. Try to scale them down by a factor. Is it correct that you want to rotate the plane continuously as long as the mouse is not at the screen center?